# How to properly write out a JSON file?

Tags: java, json

I've got some "items" I need to save.
Each item has an "id", an "amount" and a "desc" (description).

I want to save all this data in one file, e.g:

```
}
  id : 1, {
      amount : 500,
      desc : "foobar"
  }
  id : 2, {
      amount : 1000
      desc : "lorem"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If so how can I?
I want to do this so I'm able extract the amount/desc from a certain ID.

Comment: And the language you are using to accomplish this task is... Please, give me a hint.

Comment: Btw, the bit of code in the question is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't using valud JSON because I'm not sure how to achieve what I'm saying so I'm not sure what the format would be, I was using a semi pseudo-code text to explain. And it's Java.

Comment: @maxtaldykin how is it possible for me to do this? I want to save some sort of "profile" in the JSON. So I can call it via JSON->"profile id"->amount

Comment: 1) Pick a JSON kit for your language.  2) Construct the "tree" of objects from that kit to represent the structure of your desired JSON.  In Java these objects will be Maps and Lists, or some set of classes which behave like Maps and Lists.  3) Tell the kit to "serialize" the constructed tree.

Comment: And go to json.org and study the JSON syntax there.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ to do this easily.

```
  // construct new JSON object
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

  obj.put("id",     1);
  obj.put("amount", 500);
  obj.put("desc",   "foobar");

  // print it to console
  System.out.print(obj);

  // get elements
  int id = obj.get("id");
  String desc = obj.get("desc");
```

This code will print well-formed JSON object to console:

```
{"id":1,"amount":500,"desc":"foobar"}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to replace 'new Integer(1)' with just '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a tutorial for JSON in java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html. This web page shows you how to write JSON: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/, it looks like it's a library so you might need to download the library.